# Python Using Windwos API DevicePowerEnumDevices Returning is always 0

Tags: python, ctypes

Python Using Windwos API `DevicePowerEnumDevices` Returning is always 0
I can't find the reason
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-TW/windows/win32/api/powrprof/nf-powrprof-devicepowerenumdevices

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import windll
from ctypes import sizeof
from ctypes import create_string_buffer
from ctypes import POINTER,byref
from ctypes import wintypes


PowrProf = windll.LoadLibrary('PowrProf.dll')
Kernel32 = windll.LoadLibrary('Kernel32.dll')

DevicePowerOpen = PowrProf.DevicePowerOpen()

QueryIndex = 0
QueryInterpretationFlags = 0x08000000
QueryFlags = 0x00000001|0x00000004

pReturnBuffer = create_string_buffer(b'\000'*32)
pBufferSize = byref(ctypes.c_uint64(32))
pReturnBuffer = Kernel32.LocalAlloc(0x0040, pBufferSize)


Return = PowrProf.DevicePowerEnumDevices(
                                        QueryIndex,
                                        QueryInterpretationFlags,
                                        QueryFlags,
                                        pReturnBuffer,
                                        pBufferSize,
                                        )
print("Return = ",Return )


DevicePowerClose = PowrProf.DevicePowerClose()

Kernel32.LocalFree(pReturnBuffer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your buffer is too small.  From your [linked documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-TW/windows/win32/api/powrprof/nf-powrprof-devicepowerenumdevices):

> `[out, optional] pReturnBuffer`
>
> Pointer to a buffer that receives the requested information.
>
> `[in, out] pBufferSize`
>
> The size, in bytes, of the return buffer.
>
> **Note  If pReturnBuffer is NULL, pBufferSize will be filled with the
> size needed to return the data.**

Call `DevicePowerEnumDevices` with a null return buffer and `pBufferSize` will contain the size of the buffer for that returned index:

```py
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as w

PowrProf = ct.WinDLL('PowrProf')

# Recommend always defining .argtypes and .restype for each function.
# It helps ctypes convert parameters from Python to C and detect errors.
PowrProf.DevicePowerOpen.argtypes = w.ULONG,
PowrProf.DevicePowerOpen.restype = w.BOOLEAN
PowrProf.DevicePowerEnumDevices.argtypes = w.ULONG,w.ULONG,w.ULONG,w.PBYTE,w.PULONG
PowrProf.DevicePowerEnumDevices.restype = w.BOOLEAN
PowrProf.DevicePowerClose.argtypes = ()
PowrProf.DevicePowerClose.restype = w.BOOLEAN

DEVICEPOWER_HARDWAREID = 0x80000000
PDCAP_D0_SUPPORTED = 0x00000001
PDCAP_D2_SUPPORTED = 0x00000004

print('open =',PowrProf.DevicePowerOpen(0))

QueryIndex = 0
QueryInterpretationFlags = DEVICEPOWER_HARDWAREID
QueryFlags = PDCAP_D0_SUPPORTED | PDCAP_D2_SUPPORTED

while True:
    size = w.ULONG()

    # call with None to get required size of returned buffer
    PowrProf.DevicePowerEnumDevices(QueryIndex,
                                    QueryInterpretationFlags,
                                    QueryFlags,
                                    None,
                                    ct.byref(size))

    #allocate the buffer
    buffer = (w.BYTE * size.value)()

    if not PowrProf.DevicePowerEnumDevices(QueryIndex,
                                        QueryInterpretationFlags,
                                        QueryFlags,
                                        buffer,
                                        ct.byref(size)):
        break

    # Returned buffer for DEVICEPOWER_HARDWAREID is a wide multi-string value,
    # each null-terminated and the end double null-terminated
    result = ct.cast(buffer,ct.POINTER(w.WCHAR))[:size.value // ct.sizeof(w.WCHAR)]
    print(result.rstrip('\x00').split('\x00'))
    QueryIndex += 1

print('close =',PowrProf.DevicePowerClose())
```

Output (truncated):

```
open = 1
['PCI\\VEN_11AB&DEV_4364&SUBSYS_81F81043&REV_12', 'PCI\\VEN_11AB&DEV_4364&SUBSYS_81F81043', 'PCI\\VEN_11AB&DEV_4364&CC_020000', 'PCI\\VEN_11AB&DEV_4364&CC_0200']
['ACPI\\VEN_PNP&DEV_0C01', 'ACPI\\PNP0C01', '*PNP0C01']
 ...
['PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_3A3E&SUBSYS_82EA1043&REV_00', 'PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_3A3E&SUBSYS_82EA1043', 'PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_3A3E&CC_040300', 'PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_3A3E&CC_0403']
['ms_l2tpminiport']
close = 1
```

Comment: what does it mean ？                                                           result = ct.cast(buffer,ct.POINTER(w.WCHAR))[:size.value // ct.sizeof(w.WCHAR)]

Comment: @poandy The function buffer was a `BYTE*` but the data returned is actually `WCHAR*` data, so the buffer pointer is cast to the `WCHAR*` type.  The string slicing converts the data at the pointer to a Python Unicode string of the correct length.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I have another question Why should the  if loop be used `not`      `if not PowrProf.DevicePowerEnumDevices`

Comment: Why `buffer = (w.BYTE * size.value)()` add ( ) at the end

Comment: @poandy When it fails there are no more devices to enumerate and it breaks from the loop.

Comment: @poandy `w.BYTE * size` is a *type*, calling it creates an *instance* of the type.

Comment: previously replied "The string slicing converts the data at the pointer to a Python Unicode string of the correct length." I don't understand why it is converting to  Python Unicode string